# How to solve unable to locate package in termux

Tags: termux-linux

I want to install this tool in termux,

Stable build (packaged release):
wget https://github.com/smicallef/spiderfoot/archive/v4.0.tar.gz
tar zxvf v4.0.tar.gz
cd spiderfoot-4.0
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
python3 ./sf.py -l 127.0.0.1:5001
Development build (cloning git master branch):
git clone https://github.com/smicallef/spiderfoot.git
cd spiderfoot
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
python3 ./sf.py -l 127.0.0.1:5001

I want answer of this problem.